# How do we set Max failed attempts for Paypal recurring subscription

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am working on PayPal subscription section for a MVC application.
We have an option for monthly recurring subscription in our application.  I am using the subscription buttons.
As per requirement we need to CANCEL the recurring profile when the third payment attempt fails.

As of now the first two payment failure time I am getting the  IPN notification of the type (txn_type) as  “recurring_payment_failed”. 
At the time of third payment failure I am getting the  IPN notification of the type (txn_type) as  “recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment”

The issue is in the third IPN notification from the payapal (“recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment”) we are not seeing  “Subscr_id”.
But the “Subscr_id is required to cancel the recurring profile.

1. Does the “recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment” notifiacation not have the “subscr_id”?
2. From the research I found that we can set the "max failed payments" from the paypal. How do I set the same?

As of maximum payment failed attempt is 3.  Where do we set this value 3?

I am stuck with this issue. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: For question1 check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866602/correct-paypal-ipn-variable-for-suspended-subscriptions